# Relation of cuncti and cunctare?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, word-comparison

I know the word cuncti/ae/a means "all", but then I came across the word cunctare or cunctari, alternatively, which means "to hesitate".

Do these two words share a common etymology to some extent?

Comment: No "narrower" a view than to suggest CAP & CAPE, COP & COPE, MAT & MATE, are related: vowel sounds are meaningful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably not.

According to *[Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=cunctus&filter=CUTF8)*, ***cunctus*** "all" is a contraction of *coniunctus* "bound together", from *con-* "together" and *iungo* "to bind". *Iungo* is from Proto-Indo-European **(H)iug-* "yoke". But De Vaan does not mention this etymology; he only says *cunctus* may be a contraction of *concitus*, from *con-* and *cieo* "to move, incite". He adds that *Ernout & Meillet* reject this etymology. *Cieo* is from Proto-Indo-European **keih2-* "begin to move", according to De Vaan.

***Cunctor*** "hesitate" is from Proto-Indo-European **ḱ(e/o)nk-(eie-)* "to hang, falter, hesitate", according to De Vaan and [Philippa](http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/hangen), and it is cognate with English *hang*.

So the two words are probably not in any way related.

Comment: I think, it's an interesting phenomenon that langages build nearly identical word-stems without any relation in their meaning. Like the word 'malum', which has (I think) at least 3 different meanings (bad, apple and mast of a boat). Is there a linguistic term for such words?

Comment: You could call them homonyms or false cognates? The process is convergence, as in convergent evolution. Mast is *mālus, -i*, so most forms are identical.

Comment: mălus “bad” is not a homonym either of mālus f. “apple” or of mālus m. “mast”, though the three words are homographs.

Comment: @fdb: Oh, well, if you use the narrow definition, then, yes.